# SSH takes ~2 minutes to connect

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall

I made some changes to my firewall (blocking outside dns and forcing it through my dns server), and I think that may be related to why it takes a minute to connect to user@192.168.1.2? See output -vvv in the pastebin. I tried googling the part where it gets stuck and I'm stumped. `UseDNS` is set to `no`.

https://pastebin.com/WMAyrnv1 <--Log here, I've noted where it gets stuck

Edit: Updated Pastebin link with some information.

Answer (score 0):

Where does it get stuck? It might be the reverse resolving. Once you login into 192.168.1.2 try to resolve the ip you came from:

```
host origin_ip
```

You can get the origin_ip with one of these:

```
echo $SSH_CLIENT
echo $SSH_CONNECTION
```

If that takes a long time, you know what the problem is. You could then add the reverse zone to your DNS or set UseDNS to "no" in sshd_config.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned : I put a note in the log where it's stuck

Comment: `$ time host $(echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk {'print $1'})
4.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer unifi.

real 0m2.013s
user 0m0.006s
sys 0m0.004s
`

Comment: Does `ssh -4 user@192.168.1.2` work as expected? If not, you might want to check [why is my ssh login slow?](https://superuser.com/questions/166359/why-is-my-ssh-login-slow).

Comment: `ssh -4 user@192.168.1.2` is considerably faster, but still takes 20 seconds, which is much longer than normal (1-2s). `UseDNS` is already set to `no` as suggested in the linked post.

Comment: Good! That might point to an double stack resolving issue. Note that `UseDNS no` is ignored if you have a host.deny file. Also, since you "blocked outside DNS", check that /etc/resolv.conf doesn't list anything outside of your network, because that would create a delay. Maybe a tcpdump/wireshark on the outgoing interface of 192.168.1.2 can give you more info. Hard to solve with the information given, but likely a DNS issue, so you can filter for UDP port 53.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly, I actually ended up finding another post and I solved my problem by setting `UsePAM` to `no`. But yeah, I still think it is related to blocking port 53 to anywhere that isn't my PiHole.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer in another post- https://serverfault.com/questions/792486/ssh-connection-takes-forever-to-initiate-stuck-at-pledge-network

> changed UsePAM from yes to no in sshd_config file